# Ciclo de vida de varios Fragment en un ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, viewpager

Este es mi primera pregunta ya que hasta ahora siempre he podido solucionar mis problemas a través de esta comunidad.

El caso es que tengo un ViewPager2 con 5 fragment que recopilan diversa información para grabar en una BD. Todos los fragment guardan la información en un viewmodel en la activity. Fuera del ViewPager, en la activity tengo un botón que graba toda la información que se ha recogido en la viewmodel. El error se produce cuando estando visualizado el fragment 5, desde el botón intento comprobar si un campo del fragment 1 está vacío para lanzar una alerta y que aparezca ese frame.

Para eso utilizo en la activity un procedimiento de validación de campos: (Es un ejemplo, el código es más extenso)

```
 private fun checkInputs(): Boolean {
       this.supportFragmentManager.fragments[0].let {it->
            if (ViewModel.datos.value?.number?.length!! < 5) {
                viewPager.currentItem = 0
                avisoCampo(it.numberEt)
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
}
```

Compruebo que el valor que ha introducido el usuario tiene 5 digitos y si no  intento que se visualice el fragment 1 y haga focus sobre el campo en cuestion.

Esto funciona mientras el fragment 1 no pasa por su ciclo onDetach. En el momento que visualizo el cuarto frame el fragment 1 activa onDetach y la rutina anterior produce un error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: it.numberEt must not be null

Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo: Para evitar que el fragment_1 pase a Detach cuando visualizo el fragment_5 solo he tenido que hacer:

```
ViewPager.offscreenPageLimit=4
```

Esto es el número de paginas que existen sin destruirse a los lados de la actual, aunque he probado con el valor 1 y funciona igual.

Comment: te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta